# Cannot push values into an array from withing do ... while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I've searched and searched and can't find anyone with a similar problem.

I have a do ... while loop with code to push values from each record into four different arrays. All seems fine except that the arrays are empty (giving me the Warning: division by zero).

I am able to echo the four values for each record as well as the unix timestamp for each order date within the loop, so the values are correct for each record but the arrays are empty. I tried commenting out the conditional statement around the block of array[] code in the loop, but no difference.

Also tried array_push instead just to see; again, no difference.

I am a newbie, and for the life of me can't see why the arrays aren't getting populated.

This is the code outside the loop:

```
// set timezone and $one_year and $year_limit variables (used in the do-while loop)
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
       $one_year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
       $year_limit = strtotime("-1 year");

// create the empty arrays for each rating
$total_vals = array();
$food_vals = array();
$service_vals = array();
$atmo_vals = array();

// get the average for each rating
$total_avg = round((array_sum($total_vals)) / (count($total_vals)));
$food_avg = round((array_sum($food_vals)) / (count($food_vals)));
$service_avg = round((array_sum($service_vals)) / (count($service_vals)));
$atmo_avg = round((array_sum($atmo_vals)) / (count($atmo_vals)));
```

This is the loop:

```
<?php do { ?>
  <?php 
  // create unix timestamp from order_date
  $pub_date = strtotime($row_getReviews['order_date']);

  // add rate values from each record to the arrays if less than 1 year old
  if($pub_date - $one_year < $year_limit) { // tried commenting the condition out
 $total_vals[] = $row_getReviews['total_rate'];
 $food_vals[] = $row_getReviews['food_rate'];
 $service_vals[] = $row_getReviews['service_rate'];
 $atmo_vals[] = $row_getReviews['atmo_rate'];
 }
  ?>    

<!-- html, css, etc here to display text and more -->

<?php } while ($row_getReviews = mysql_fetch_assoc($getReviews)); ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Create empty arrays

Loop

Get averages
```

In that order. Be sure that the loop occurs before you get averages.

And use any sort of loop other than do ... while, so that you have data on the first iteration for the reasons Mayhem stated.

Comment: OK! Moving the block of average code after (outside) the loop worked. Placed it after the while statement of the do ... while loop and got the averages from the arrays (populated as expected). Since I want to display the averages at the top of the page it looks like i'll need to loop through the records twice, first for the averages, and then for the detailed values (text, etc) for the individual records. I was trying to use just the one loop. But it appears I do need the do ... while loop, at least for displaying the individuals records. Thanks!

Comment: Of course Ted. Sorry, my first time asking a question here. One caveat though, with the do ... while loop everything is correct. I moved all the code above the head: set arrays; do ... while loop to get the values; calculate averages; rewind recordset. All is well. (And thisMayhem said to move it after, I just didn't catch that.)